# Keep all Animations Nodes instances in one layer

Tags: compositing-nodes, animation-nodes, layers

I'm making a simple animation with AN but for compositing reasons I need to keep all instances of an object in the layer 1 and the rest of my objects in layer 2.
[image: my instances generated]
[image: instances stay on both layers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, create a loop and add a Object list for Iterator and connect your object list from the Object Transform Output or whatever list you are using to the iteration, and use the Add > Object > Layer Visibility Output node and connect your Object output to it. and use the Type of "Single" and the number of your layer in the Layer Index, and if you want to keep it on several layers use the Multiple Type and select your desired layers.
Remember that layers have the index equal to the layer number minus one, so, they go from 0 to 19.
Illustrative image:[image: The object layer is kept on the first layer]

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, Gresthol! I was wondering why all object instances from other node trees were jumping to the active layer when adding an icosphere and increasing its subdivision levels. Your solution keeps everything where it should be. Thanks!